# SQL get data containing 1 type only

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, filter

I want to get data if R1 has all 1 or R2 has all 1 by date.

Input:

| Date | R1 | R2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 26-7-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 26-7-2021 | 0 | 1 |
| 26-7-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 27-7-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 27-7-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 28-7-2021 | 0 | 1 |
| 28-7-2021 | 0 | 1 |

Result:

| Date | R1 | R2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27-7-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 27-7-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 28-7-2021 | 0 | 1 |
| 28-7-2021 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: don't ask people to complete your task/writing queries for you. Instead come up with pain point, what difficulties you are facing.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will add my code next time.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you return 4 rows?  Why not just return the dates where this occurs?

```
select date, min(r1), min(r2)
from t
group by date
having min(r1) = max(r1) and min(r2) = max(r2);
```

Comment: I want to filter row by row first, then calculate other steps later. Used to calculate all group by date but not correctly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a windowed conditional count:**

```sql
SELECT
  t.Date,
  t.R1,
  t.R2
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        CountZeroR1 = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.R1 = 0 THEN 1 END)
             OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(t.Date AS date)),
        CountZeroR2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.R2 = 0 THEN 1 END)
             OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(t.Date AS date))
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE t.CountZeroR1 = 0 OR t.CountZeroR2 = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use case when but not in nested select, so it still filters all mixed result. I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MIN()` window function to get the rows that have only `1`s in either `R1` or `R2` for a specific date:

```
SELECT Date, R1, R2 
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         MIN(R1) OVER (PARTITION BY Date) min_r1,
         MIN(R2) OVER (PARTITION BY Date) min_r2
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE 1 IN (min_r1, min_r2)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4718209c5e7730e826bb0e004a016653).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a new approach to me. I will try your solution again.